# Grub menu not opening

Tags: grubrescue

Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems: -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) -Check rootdelays= (did the system wait long enough?) -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules: ls /dev) ALERT! UUID=d0dbe034-ecdd-4ac8-9a77-2dbbfae7ba04 does not exist.Dropping to a shell!

Busybox V1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) build-in shell(ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)

Comment: What brand/model system? UEF or BIOS? new install or one that worked before? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/